# C++: How to search for quoatations using stacks

Tags: c++, stack, text-parsing

I have to create a program that reads in a text file and checks for matching parenthesis, brackets, `[]`, quote symbols, and block comment. If there is an imbalance it returns false, if it is balanced it returns true.

I have done `[] () {}` and need help making it work for `/* */`, `"  "`, and `' '` where everything inside the single/double quotes and the block comments are ignored. I've tried many things but have been unsuccessful in getting them to work.

Comment: You don't need a stack -  you just need a counter. +1 when you see opens, -1 when you see closes. If your result isn't 0 when you've finished reading, error.

Comment: what if the text had something like `*/ text /*`? Then it would still result in 0, yet the code is wrong

Comment: Good point. Also if you ever go negative, that's an error. :)

Comment: How would I look for an open and closed single quote or double quote when the open and closed look the same

Comment: Assuming you're not trying to parse Python, that's fine. Consider even and odd parity. Every even sight is an open, ever odd is a close.

Comment: I need it to print out "`pair matching [ and ]`" if it finds a pair, and `"unbalanced symbol } at line x` if it doesnt. I don't know if I can do those using this method which is why I'm required to use a stack but I can give it a try

Comment: Quotes will be weird because you'll have to wait until everything has been parse to give an error. This is why text editors with syntax highlighting are weird when you start a quote and treat the rest of your program as an unfinished string.

Comment: If you're writing a parser, you should really be using [lex/yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) or some other parser generator..

Comment: @StacksAndParsing One question.  Is `/* */` considered a comment block?  If so, what if there are mismatched braces or parentheses in the comments?  Your code needs to skip everything and just make your current code a no-op.  So I don't see how you're going to retrofit what you've done to handle this scenario.  You have to treat it separate and apart from your current code.

Comment: @paulmckenzie yes and yes. everything inside the block comments is to be ignored. Same goes for quotations

Comment: @StacksAndParsing I think the problem is like my comment suggested -- you're trying to retrofit your current code to handle this scenario you're having difficulty with.  That really can't be done easily.  You have to lay that code you've written aside, and write a "comment function".  Then when you have the two code samples (your existing one and the one that recognizes comments), build some sort of shell around them that knows when one should be invoked over the other.

Comment: @StacksAndParsing Just to continue -- To me this would be a better approach, because by the time you get anything done, you've ripped your current (working) code to shreds or made it so hard to figure out, any issues become near impossible to fix.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see what you are saying. I'll try to create a separate code dedicated to these

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951281/c-stacks-and-printing-something-out-when-you-reach-the-end-of-a-file-or-when

Answer (score 1):

The program now needs to handle two *states/modes* instead of one:

- It starts in "matching mode", putting `( { [` on the stack and popping `) } ]` if they match.
- As soon as you read a `/*`, you enter "comment mode" and ignore everything until you read `*/`, at which point you return to "matching mode" with the previous stack. The same goes for `"` and `'`.

If you reach end of input while in "comment mode" you print out: "unbalanced symbol" with the symbol that made you enter that mode.

Comment: I've written code doing as you say but I have one problem: If it finds a `/*` and then goes into comment mode and never finds a matching pair in the entire file, I need to print out `"unbalanced symbol /*"`. So what I did was: (note: `/*` is in the stack): go into comment mode, and if you reach the end of file, print out `unbalanced symbol /*`, otherwise read in another character into letter.

Comment: I'll edit the post and add the code so that it makes more sense to you, please give me a minute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951281/c-stacks-and-printing-something-out-when-you-reach-the-end-of-a-file-or-when

Answer (score 0):

you just have to do the same thing you have done with the parenthesis create stack for the opening and closing and then pop each stack one by one and then check the validation by comparing the popped values