# C++: Stacks and Printing something out when you reach the end of a file or when reading the last character in a file

Tags: ifstream

I need to read from a file, character by character.

My specific problem:

If it finds a `/*`, it puts them into the stack, and then goes into "comment mode" where it ignores everything until it finds a `*/`. *If it never finds the matching pair `*/*` in the entire file, it should print out "unbalanced symbol /*" but it never prints that*

Comment: check if you don't need to escape the '/', and if it reads it like that... you could test by "cout" each character so you can see what is founding...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: How to search for quoatations using stacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948673/c-how-to-search-for-quoatations-using-stacks)

Answer (score 1):

The program now needs to handle two *states/modes* instead of one:

- It starts in "matching mode", putting `( { [` on the stack and popping `) } ]` if they match.
- As soon as you read a `/*`, you enter "comment mode" and ignore everything until you read `*/`, at which point you return to "matching mode" with the previous stack. You don't need a stack while in this mode. The same goes for `"` and `'`.

If you reach end of input while in "comment mode" you print out: "unbalanced symbol" with the symbol that made you enter that mode.

Comment: I've gotten it to go from matching mode to comment mode and back to matching mode. The only problem is, if I enter comment mode and don't find the closing `*/`, it doesn't print out "unbalanced symbol"

Comment: May I recommend firing up the debugger that comes with your tool chain and stepping through the code to see where it deviates from the expected?